# It is necessary to implement the link so that the English version don't have the prefix /en/

Tags: php, modx

There are 3 versions of the site: Spanish, Ukrainian and English, it is necessary to implement this in such a way that the English version does not have the /en/ prefix
It should be something like this:
https://example.com/terms/ https://example.com/es/terms/ https://example.com/ua/terms/

```
<ul class="site-footer__bottom-text-two list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <a href="/[[!*context_key:is=`web`:then=`ua`]][[!*context_key:is=`en`:then=`en`]]  [[!*context_key:is=`ru`:then=`ru`]]/terms/">[[%terms? &namespace=`lang` &language=`[[++cultureKey]]`]]</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I may not have shown all the context that is needed, but I would like to get an understanding of how this can be implemented. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your English context will be used by default, so you need to go into its settings (*yourwebsite.com/manager/?a=context*) and make sure there is no `/en/` prefix in appropriate *path* settings. Also please check that your context is loaded in the root `index.php` file, basically there is `web` context call. Also be careful with next MODX update, it'll rewrite `index.php` with default value so you should aware there and update file accordingly.